# Inserting Data into Table based on Same Data in Current table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, sql-insert

I have a table, with the structure below:

```
create table student_course(
student_id integer,
course_id integer,
primary key (student_id, course_id)
);
```

Here is my use case: students who select certain courses need to take another assistant course. For example, a student who has enrolled in a course with `course_id` of `101` must take an additional course with `course_id` of `300`, because 101 is so hard and they should get the tutorial course of 300 at the same time.

I need to create a SQL query to add the additional entries for students taking the pre-requisite course to this `student_course` table; in this case, adding new rows for students taking 101 to take 300 as well.

I am now using `select * from students_course where course_id = 101`, then exporting this data to update students who are enrolled 101 to 300. Finally, I import these exported students with 101 again. Is there a better SQL query that I can use to insert data from my current table?

Comment: From where you are fetching the value of course_id ? Or you are assigning it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to basically use the insert query with select .Try the below query:

```
insert into student_course(student_id,courseId)
    select student_id, 300
    from student_course
    where course_id = 101;
```

**Note**: Please make sure that you don't have any student with course_id 101 already existing with course_id 300, otherwise this query won't work.

Comment: Thank you, this works. I think if go further, there are some students already remained, we could use subquery where not in, is that correct?

Comment: No, that won't work directly, you will have to make self join and then proceed

Comment: I think I got the idea is "insert into student_course(student_id,courseId) select student_id,300 from student_course where course_id =101 and student_id not in (select student_id from student_course where course_id = 300);"

Comment: nsert into student_course(student_id,courseId) select student_id,300 from student_course where course_id =101 and student not in (select student_id from student_course where course_id = 300);

Comment: but I am thinking use subquery is slower than join, I could also use self left join

Comment: yeah you can..that depends on amount of data you have

Comment: this could be used in another case that some students they do not select the 300 and we set a deadline, once deadline is reached, all the students not in 300 could be insert into 300. Thank you so much, I understand a lot.